# Set logo size correctly + delete padding

Tags: html, css

The theme I'm using was automatically resizing my logo to a certain size. I've tried to edit the css file by adding `width: 100%;` in `.header .logo {` element as you can see in the code below:

```
Header
*/
.header_container {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.header {
  height: auto;
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 101;
  background: #fff;
}
.header .header_top {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  direction: ltr;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .header .header_top {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
}
.header .header_top > .row > .columns {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 70px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .header .header_top > .row > .columns {
    padding: 0 0.9375em;
  }
}
.header .logo {
  display: table;
  min-height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header .logo .logolink {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.header .logo .logoimg {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 40px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .header .logo .logoimg {
    max-height: 70px;
  }
}
```

This made the logo appear the way I wanted, but now I have huge top and bottom paddings and I don't know how to take them out. [Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4lST.png)

Also, the social media icons show up lower than the logo (they should be in line with the logo).

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I think we need the HTML code as well to be sure of the right answer. You can also [run the code live in your question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/#how-do-i-make-a-stack-snippet?) if you like.

Comment: I only have the php file of the header of the WP theme I'm using. The code is too long for me to paste it in a comment. Link: http://collabedit.com/662n9 (enter a random name to see it). Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the link!

Comment: Link: collabedit.com/662n9

Answer (score 0):

I can't make a proper mock-up with the files you gave me; I don't have the rest of the stylesheet for the menu and the social buttons, and I don't have the HTML for those either (you've only given me `<?php?>` tags there). However, it seems likely that the only problem is that the `.logo` element, having a width of 100%, is simply pushing those elements out of the way, so the menu button appears on its own line above, and the social buttons appear on their own line below.

This is probably the only reason the header is too tall, so the padding issue should go away on its own.

So, remove the line you added, and target the `<img>` tag directly with a width of much less than 100%.

The following CSS seems to be necessary to make the image fit within the size of the container you give it:

```
header .logo .logoimg {
  width: 100%;
}

header.fixed .logo .logoimg {
  width: auto;
}
```

Also, change the `medium-4` class on the children of `<div class="row full-width-row">` to `medium-3`, `medium-6`, and `medium-3`repectively. This gives the title (medium-6) six-twelfths of the space, with the others getting 25% each. That's as small as you can make the social buttons.

Comment: Here is the website in case you want to have a look: [site](http://www.glamfacts.com) I'm not sure what you mean by `<img>` tag? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use "unset" property as it has low support. Use "auto" instead

Comment: @Szymon Thanks, I've made that change.